# URL validation using Javascript doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, validation

I use the following validation for url:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("urlValidatorJS", function (value, element) {
    var RegExp = (/^HTTP|HTTP|http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?[A-Za-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z]{2,40}(:[0-9]{1,40})?(\/.*)?$/);
    return this.optional(element) || RegExp.test(value);
}, "The url is incorrect");
```

For some reason the following invalid url is valid according the validation above:
http://www.example.com/ %20here.html   (url with space).

How can I fix the validation?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (\/.*)?
> ```

You said the (optional) last thing in the URL is a slash followed by any number of *any* character.

Be more specific than `.` if you don't want to allow spaces.

Comment: @Quentin- so what exactly should I write in the Regex?

Comment: see my answer for that: use `\S` instead of `.` as your "any" character as it includes everything but whitespaces. Also you're missing some not too uncommon types of URLs such as `http://some.other.example.com`

Comment: @Niklas- so how can I not miss them?

Comment: @Niklas- the client validation of the js still doesn't work well....http://www.example.com/ %20here.html  is still valid

Comment: using the regex I wrote in my answer example.com %20here.html does not match. I can't see where your mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

At first: there already is a validation module from jQuery which you could use.

This would be your regex to match the URLs you mentioned (don't miss the i flag in the end!):

```
/^(https?:\/\/)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+([\-\.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(\/\S*)?/i
```

You were missing that there can also be other adresses like `http://some.other.example.com`. Also as mentioned in the other answer your identifier `.` was too greedy. I replaced it with `\S`for any non-whitespace character. You also had some unnecessary identifiers like `{1}` and your additional `HTTP` in the first part of your regex.

You can also use pages like [regex101](http://regex101.com) to examine your regex and try it on different strings. It also explains each part of your regex so you can debug it better.

Comment: @Niklas- for what is the i in the end? I get error in the editor when I add it

Comment: the i is a regex flag to make everything case insensitive. I think you might have to delete your surrounding brackets so it will be `var RegExp = / ... /i`

Comment: @Niklas- I don't get the error in the js file. I get the error in groovy file:   static constraints = {
        url (blank:false, matches: /^(https?:\/\/)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+([\-\.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(\/\S*)?/i)
        type (nullable:false)
    }

Comment: it seems like groovy has a different notation of regex flags: [documentation](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/wiki/index.php/Regular_Expressions_in_Groovy#Example_usage_of_Match_Flags)

Comment: I write over the server validation which grails (groovy on rails) have

Comment: I don't know about neither groovy nor groovy on rails. You gave JavaScript code and I fixed your JavaScript code. if you want a fix for grails you should edit your question or write a new one to explain your problem about grails and also tag the question as a grails